# ios MapKit MKOverlayView animation happening instantly

Tags: ios, animation, mapkit, overlay

I am trying to animate the alpha value of a MapKit overlay view (specifically an MKCircleView) in iOS 5 using the following code:

```
-(void) animateCircle:(MKCircle*)circle onMap:(MKMapView*) mapView
{
    MKCircleView * circleView = (MKCircleView*) [mapView viewForOverlay:circle];
    UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 
                          delay:0.0 
                        options:options 
                     animations:^(void) { circleView.alpha = 0.9; }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {} 
     ];    
}
```

The alpha value of the overlay is changing as I want, but it is jumping there instantaneously rather than animating over the specified duration.

Can anyone suggest what might be wrong?  Perhaps animation on overlay views os more complex with blocks than I had thought.

Answer (score 0):

Core Animation has interesting behavior when concurrent animations effect the same view... If you try to animate a view before the view's last animation finished, it will assume you intended the subsequent animation to start from the desired end-state of the initial one. This can result in jumps of frames as well as jumps of alpha values.

In your case, this view is likely being animated by something else. Try locating and removing the other animation / or'ing in UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState to its options.